# XmlReader hangs after first Read

Tags: c#, xmlreader, networkstream

I'm trying to read an xml stream through TcpClient:

```
TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient("172.16.1.222", 80);
```

After creating the stream as

```
NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
```

I proceed on to read:

```
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(serverStream);
while (r.Read())
{
    if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        somename = r.Name.ToString();
    }
    if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text && somename == "abc")
    {
          readBoxID.Text = r.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

This works fine for the first stream. I see the data fine but then it hangs with the following error at `while(r.Read)`:

> Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the server sends something the client could read? The "error" message you see in the debugger just says that the Read method is blocked waiting for data from the server.

Comment: When are you getting this error, during debugging? or running your app in normal mode?

Comment: As @dtb mentioned, its not error from Read(). Read() is sync call, after it reads all data, it blocks the current thread and wait there for more data.

Comment: So, it's not really the error - the data stops coming in? Any suggestion on how I can see that there is no data and stop the process? I just tried closing the reader: r.Close() but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: The server should send a complete, well-formed XML document to the client and then close the connection.

Comment: The server does not close the connection and I do not have any control over that. Is there a way around?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the server?

Comment: It's actually a box I have locally - not connected to world. What it does is that it reads through a sensor and streams out xml for the devices it finds through the sensor. It can be run in a single or loop mode. In both modes, the program hangs after the first read.

Comment: I just tried one more thing: I replaced the readBoxText method with MessageBox.Show method and surprisingly, this one keeps on reading the next xml as long as I keep pressing the OK button on the message box. The program does not hang!

Comment: A simple workaround is to simply not call Read once you've got the information you need. But I think it'd be better you try to find out how communication with the server is supposed to work. Without any link to documentation/manufacturer/anything it's nearly impossible to help you with this, sorry.